# Why does custom action bar background style hide text?

Tags: android

i am tuning my action bar, the problem is that when i set the background property in my child theme then action bar text will disappear:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

If i override the background then the remaining properties should come from the parent theme by my logic, this includes that the text is still visible.

In order to get the text back i need to write the following:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showTitle</item>
```

Why do i need to write that? Why does setting the background remove the text from the parent theme? Thanks in advance for the clarifications.

Comment: You can use tool bar and set the bar color from your layout, that can be customized very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inheriting from an incorrect style. Instead of inheriting from `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` make your `actionBarStyle` be a descendant of one of `AppCompat` styles, e.g. `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid`.

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- override attributes here -->
</style>
```